# 3 object sampled by two people 3 times each, probability one person samples objects 2 times while the other person sampled the same object 0 times

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My current progress: 3 object sampled 6 times has 28 possibilities, (3+6-1)!/(6!(3-1)!) = 28. In 3 of these, either object is sampled 6 times. In 6 of these, either object is sampled 5 times, and one of the other two objects 1 time. When either object is sampled 4 times, the remaining objects can be sampled either 1 time on both one time, or, two times on either 2 times, 6 + 3 = 9 combinations in total. 3 + 6 + 9 = 18, 10 remaining. Either object sampled 3 times, either other object can be sampled 3 times, 3 in total. 18 + 3 = 21, 7 remaining. Further when either object sampled 3 times, the other two can be sampled 2+1 times, in 2 ways, so, 6 more combinations. 21 + 6 = 27, 1 remaining. And, all three objects can be sampled 2 times, at the same time, adding the last 1 combination, 27 + 1 = 28.

6 + 6 + 1 = 13 combinations include objects sampled 2 times. Another way to think about that, the two other objects sampled 4 times when one object is sampled two times, can be sampled in 5 different ways, one way is all three objects sampled twice (+1), and the rest (4) multiplied with 3 ways to get that, is 12.

Testing the scenario with a script gives 19.7% success rate. 13/28 is 46%.

```
# cook your dish here

import random

objects = 3
samples = 6

success = 0

iterations = 100000

for x in range(iterations):

    Alice = [0]*objects
    Bob = [0]*objects

    for i in range(samples):
        randomNumber = random.randint(0, objects-1)
        if i%2: Bob[randomNumber] += 1
        else: Alice[randomNumber] += 1
    
    for i in range(objects):
        if Bob[i] == 2 and Alice[i] == 0:
            success+=1
        
print(success/iterations*100, "%", sep="")
```

Background and motivation, why the question is interesting or important: learning basic combinatorics to think about simple attack vector scenarios in game theoretical systems I work on for my own reasons.

Possible strategies: this is super easy math, I'm just not good at it. Anyone who is good at it knows strategy for it like most people know how to ride a bike.